# Parser Combinators in OO C

Tags: c, object-oriented, parsing, functional-programming

In trying to understand and use the [Parser Combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser_combinator) concept, I've coded up as close an analogue as I could manage within the constraints of the C language.

C doesn't have first-class functions or dynamic code generation, so instead I use a pseudo-object-oriented approach which builds a tree to represent the parser, with function-pointers at each node.

A Parser returns a list of results, so this is implemented with singly-linked lists. But trees and lists are not the focus of this code so the program just uses them without much fuss. Perhaps some operations should be abstracted, like searching to the end of the list.

This program uses two `typedef`d pointers. Not trying to hide it or anything, just factoring out lots of extra *s.

What improvements can I make to the overall organization of the program? Or any parts that could be more clear?

pc3.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct parser *parser;
typedef struct result *result;
typedef result (*handler)( parser p, char *input );

struct parser {
  handler test;
  parser a, b;
  int c;
};

struct result {
  result next;
  int length_matched;
};

#define new_function_for_(type) \
  type new_##type ( struct type input ){ \
    type local = calloc( sizeof *local, 1 ); \
    return  local  ?  ( *local = input ), local  :  local; \
  }
new_function_for_(parser)
new_function_for_(result)


result parse( parser p, char *input ){  return  p->test( p, input );  }
result parse_fail( parser p, char *input ){  return  NULL;  }
result parse_succeed( parser p, char *input ){
  return  new_result( (struct result){ .next = NULL, .length_matched = 0 } );
}
result parse_term( parser p, char *input ){
  return  *input == p->c  ?
    new_result( (struct result){ .next = NULL, .length_matched = 1 } ) :
    NULL;
}

result parse_alternate( parser p, char *input ){
  result res = parse( p->a, input );
  if(  res  ){
    result r = res;
    while(  r->next  ) r = r->next;
    r->next = parse( p->b, input );
    return  res;
  } else  return  parse( p->b, input );
}

void amend_lengths( result r, int length ){
  r->length_matched += length;
  if(  r->next  )  amend_lengths( r->next, length );
}

result parse_sequence_next( result r, parser p, char *input ){
  if(  ! r  )  return  NULL;
  result res = parse( p->b, input + r->length_matched );
  if(  res  ){
    amend_lengths( res, r->length_matched );
    result tail = res;
    while(  tail->next  )  tail = tail->next;
    tail->next = parse_sequence_next( r->next, p, input );
    return  res;
  } else  return  parse_sequence_next( r->next, p, input );
}

result parse_sequence( parser p, char *input ){
  result res = parse( p->a, input );
  return  parse_sequence_next( res, p, input );
}


parser fails(){  return  new_parser( (struct parser){ .test = parse_fail } ); }
parser succeeds(){  return  new_parser( (struct parser){ .test = parse_succeed } ); }

parser term( int c ){
  return  new_parser( (struct parser){ .test = parse_term, .c = c } );
}
parser alternate( parser a, parser b){
  return  new_parser( (struct parser){ .test = parse_alternate, .a = a, .b = b } );
}
parser sequence( parser a, parser b){
  return  new_parser( (struct parser){ .test = parse_sequence, .a = a, .b = b } );
}
parser many( parser a ){
  parser q = new_parser( (struct parser){ .test = parse_sequence, .a = a } );
  parser r = new_parser( (struct parser){ .test = parse_alternate, .a = q, .b = succeeds() } );
  q->b = r;
  return r;
}
parser some( parser a ){
  parser q = new_parser( (struct parser){ .test = parse_sequence, .a = a } );
  parser r = new_parser( (struct parser){ .test = parse_alternate, .a = q, .b = succeeds() } );
  q->b = r;
  return q;
}

parser char_class( char *str ){
  return  *str  ?  alternate( term( *str ), char_class( str + 1 ) )  :  fails();
}
parser string( char *str ){
  return  *str  ?  sequence( term( *str ), string( str + 1 ) )  :  succeeds();
}


void print_results( result res ){
  if(  res  )  printf( "%d ", res->length_matched ),
                 print_results( res->next );
}

void test( parser p, char *str ){
  printf( "%s:", str );
  fflush(0);
  result r = parse( p, str );
  print_results( r );
  printf( "\n" );
}

void cases( void (*test)( parser p, char *str ) ){
  parser p = string("hello");
  test( p, "hello" );
  test( p, "hell" );
  test( p, "hello w" );
  test( p, "xxxxx" );

  parser q = many( term( 'x' ) );
  test( q, "xy" );
  test( q, "xx" );
  test( q, "xxxy" );
  test( q, "xxxxy" );
  test( q, "xxxxx" );

  parser r = sequence( many( term( 'x' ) ), string( "xy" ) );
  test( r, "xy" );
  test( r, "xx" );
  test( r, "xxxy" );
  test( r, "xxxxy" );
  test( r, "xxxxx" );
}

int main(){
  cases( test );
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./pc3
hello:5 
hell:
hello w:5 
xxxxx:
xy:1 0 
xx:2 1 0 
xxxy:3 2 1 0 
xxxxy:4 3 2 1 0 
xxxxx:5 4 3 2 1 0 
xy:2 
xx:
xxxy:4 
xxxxy:5 
xxxxx:
```

Earlier drafts and discussions [in this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.lang.c/BuwBXfpgN_M/discussion). This program is partly based on a PostScript prototype discussed [in this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.lang.postscript/KiEFeJROOcM/discussion).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Or any parts that could be more clear?

```
typedef struct parser *parser;
```

Although `parser` in `struct parser` and `typedef struct parser *parser` exists in different name spaces, having one as a `struct` and the other a *pointer* is far from clear.  Suggest:

```
typedef struct parser *parser_ptr;
```

... or the equivalent.

Type def-ing a `struct` pointer should be avoided.  When needed **use different names** if the `typedef` is a pointer.  The following *looks* wrong.

```
parser q = new_parser(...
...
q->b = r; // Should not code be a q.b,  oh wait, `parser` is a pointer type.

// Looks like a block of data is being returned, no wait, its a pointer.
result parse(...) { ... }
```

Ref: [Is it a good idea to typedef pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750178/2410359)

---

Code lack comments.  A few comments, at least, would add clarity.

---

Put test cases and `main()` in another files to clearly demarcate the code and the test code.

---

No need to flush *everything*:

```
printf( "%s:", str );
//fflush(0);
fflush(stdout);
```

---

Subtle point.  When `int` is used to store a character and subsequent code interacts with `char`, the standard C library model is to treat the values as `unsigned char`.  This is important when `char` is signed and values outside `0-127` are used.  Recall `fgets()` returns values in the `unsigned char, EOF` range.

```
result parse_term( parser p, char *input ){
  // return  *input == p->c 
  // return  (unsigned char) *input == (unsigned char) (p->c)
```

---

There is testing for a *null pointer* in many places except for test code.  Hmmm.