# Axiomatic Lisp interpreter in C

Tags: c, lisp, interpreter

This is not obfuscated. Or at least, that's not the intent. Let me try to address that concern straightaway. The goal here is brevity in the vein of Strunk&White. Nor is this codegolf, although inspiration and techniques derived from that source have contributed greatly to the current state of the code.

There are a list of reference URLs and the first is to an [ioccc source](http://www.ioccc.org/1989/jar.2.c). And the third is to a [golfed interpreter](http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Essays/Incunabulum). And further down there's a link to our own sister site [code golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/284/write-an-interpreter-for-the-untyped-lambda-calculus/3290#3290) but there is also unobfuscated source available there.

Rather the purpose for the brevity of this code is so you can print it 4-up, fold it in half, and stick it in your McCarthy anthology so you can read along with the [original paper](http://edge.cs.drexel.edu/regli/Classes/Lisp_papers/McCarthy-original-LISP-paper-recursive.pdf). Well, it was primarily as an exercise for myself to delve into the mysteries of [that paper](http://www-formal.stanford.edu/jmc/recursive/recursive.html). But I share it for the former reason.

I have made extensive use of this macro to force the programming into a functional, expression-oriented style.

```
#define defun(NAME,ARGS,...) \
    int NAME ARGS { return __VA_ARGS__; }
```

This *does* make use of implicit int in the parameter lists of many function definitions. But I consider that a better choice than adding a more cumbersome FOREACH macro to add `int` where appropriate. So, this does require most compilers to use a non-pedantic interpretation of the C99 standard for the implicit int on parameter names.

I hope that accompanied with [the McCarthy paper](http://edge.cs.drexel.edu/regli/Classes/Lisp_papers/McCarthy-original-LISP-paper-recursive.pdf), the one-to-one correspondence between McCarthy's functions and these functions will be easily seen. The parts I don't like and would like suggestions upon will be highlighted after the code proper.

I trust my audience here, after the tender critiques from chux on [my](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/166064/5912) [unusual](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/176401/5912) [style](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/141013/5912). This is dense code. It is an unusual C style. But I hope the sense behind it can be seen in the spacing used to highlight parallel constructions. And the close correspondence to the function definitions in the original paper.

This is "toy" code, in that it is not employed to do any real useful work. But it is also a crucible of magical reverie. An abstract machine. My baby.

That said, I am wearing my asbestos underpants. So if something needs to be said, please say it. I need to learn. :)

[sexp.c](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/sexp.c/blob/f41edd23301a76b79c430f550b75509c6c163bac/sexp.c)

```
/* sexp.c - an integer-coded tiny lisp.
cf.
http://www.ioccc.org/1989/jar.2.c                  <-- memory 'cursors'
http://leon.bottou.org/projects/minilisp           <-- compact 'C'-able cell encoding
http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Essays/Incunabulum  <-- tiny APL interpreter
http://www-formal.stanford.edu/jmc/recursive/recursive.html  <-- original lisp paper
http://www.paulgraham.com/rootsoflisp.html                   <-- alternate presentation of core (with bugfix)
http://www.cse.sc.edu/~mgv/csce330f13/micromanualLISP.pdf    <-- original micro-manual for lisp
http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/284/write-an-interpreter-for-the-untyped-lambda-calculus/3290#3290
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096456/why-wont-my-little-lisp-quote  <-- earlier version of this program
http://www.nhplace.com/kent/Papers/Special-Forms.html   <-- FEXPRs NLAMBDAs and MACROs, oh my!
https://web.archive.org/web/20070317222311/http://www.modeemi.fi/~chery/lisp500/lisp500.c <-- similar idea
 */
#include<assert.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<stdarg.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include"ppnarg.h"   /*https://github.com/luser-dr00g/sexp.c/blob/master/ppnarg.h*/
/*defun macro thanks to Kaz Kylheku: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.c/FiC6hbH1azw/-Tiuw2oQoyAJ*/
#define defun(NAME,ARGS,...) \
    int NAME ARGS { return __VA_ARGS__; }


/* memory is organized as a large array of ints
   each int is a "word" and memory can be accessed by
       m[int]
   the int here is a cursor called herein a "pointer" (<-- always in quotes) [^codegolf jar2]*/
int*m,*n,msz; /*memory next mem-size*/

/* global environment for REPL, modified by SET, SETQ and DEFUN */
int env;

/* each word is interpreted as a 2 bit tag
   and a sizeof(int)*8-2 bit signed number. 32bit int :: 30bit + 2bit tag [^minilisp]*/
enum { TAGCONS, TAGATOM, TAGOBJ, TAGNUM,
       TAGBITS = 2,
       TAGMASK = (1U<<TAGBITS)-1 };
defun(val,(x),x>>TAGBITS)
defun(tag,(x),x&TAGMASK)
defun(  listp,(x),tag(x)==TAGCONS) /* predicates */
defun(  atomp,(x),tag(x)==TAGATOM)
defun(objectp,(x),tag(x)==TAGOBJ)
defun(numberp,(x),tag(x)==TAGNUM)
defun(  consp,(x),x&&listp(x))

/* bias the alphabet at the ascii code for T,  [<my own brilliant idea]
   this way, the word 1 means 30bit 0 + 2bit 01 :: the symbol T
        and, the word 0  ::   30bit 0 + 2bit 00 :: the list NIL
                 word 5  ::   30bit 1 + 2bit 01 :: the symbol U
                 word 9  ::   30bit 2 + 2bit 01 :: the symbol V
                 word 4  ::   30bit 1 + 2bit 00 :: the list at address 1
                 word 8  ::   30bit 2 + 2bit 00 :: the list at address 2
   tag  00 : list   : val is "pointer" to 2-cell pair
        01 : atom   : val is encoded as 5 6-bit codes packed low-to-high,
                                        with the first code biased at `enc('T')` (ie. 20)
        10 : object : val is "pointer" to an object union
        11 : number : val is a 30bit fixnum
   [^minilisp ^lisp500]
   6bit code
   0          111111 11112222 22222233 33333333 44444444 44555555 5555 6666
   01234567 89012345 67890123 45678901 23456789 01234567 89012345 6789 0123  <- general position
  " ABCDEFG HIJKLMNO PQRSTUVW XYZ_abcd efghijkl mnopqrst uvwxyz)1 2345 6789"
   -------- -------- ----
   21111111 111          0          11 11111111 22222222 22333333 3333 4444
   09876543 21098765 43210123 45678901 23456789 01234567 89012345 6789 0123  <- first char
   44444455 55555555 6666
   45678901 23456789 0123
*/
#define ALPHA "T"
#define NIL   (0)
#define T atom(ALPHA)
char *encoding = " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz)123456789";
defun(enc,(x),strchr(encoding,x)-encoding)
defun(encstr0,(char*s),*s?encstr0(s+1)<<6|enc(*s):enc(' '))
defun(encstr,(char*s),*s?encstr0(s+1)<<6|((enc(*s)+64-enc(*ALPHA))%64):enc(' '))
defun(atom,(char*s),encstr(s)<<TAGBITS|TAGATOM)
defun(number,(x),x<<TAGBITS|TAGNUM)

defun(object,(x),x<<TAGBITS|TAGOBJ)
enum objecttag { SUBR, FSUBR, SUBR2, FSUBR2 };
union object { int tag;
      struct { int tag; int (*f)(); } f;
};
int objfunc(enum objecttag t, int(*f)()){
    union object *o = (union object *)n;
    //n+=(int)ceil((double)sizeof*o/sizeof*n);
    n+=(sizeof*o+sizeof*n-1)/sizeof*n;
    o->f.tag = t;
    o->f.f = f;
    return object((int*)o-m);
}
defun(subr1,(int(*f)()),objfunc(SUBR,f))
defun(fsubr1,(int(*f)()),objfunc(FSUBR,f))
defun(subr2,(int(*f)()),objfunc(SUBR2,f))
defun(fsubr2,(int(*f)()),objfunc(FSUBR2,f))

/*manipulating lists.
  val() of course returns an int i which indexes `int *m;`
                             ^^^^^:our "pointer"  ^^^^^^:the memory
  using the commutativity of indexing in C: m[i] == *(m + i) == i[m] */
defun(cons,(x,y),*n++=x,*n++=y,(n-m)-2<<TAGBITS|TAGCONS)
defun(rplaca,(x,y),consp(x)?val(x)[m]=y:0)
defun(rplacd,(x,y),consp(x)?val(x)[m+1]=y:0)
defun(car,(x),consp(x)?val(x)[m]:0)
defun(cdr,(x),consp(x)?val(x)[m+1]:0)
defun(caar,(x),car(car(x)))
defun(cadr,(x),car(cdr(x)))
defun(cddr,(x),cdr(cdr(x)))
defun(cadar,(x),car(cdr(car(x))))
defun(caddr,(x),car(cdr(cdr(x))))
defun(cdddr,(x),cdr(cdr(cdr(x))))
defun(caddar,(x),car(cdr(cdr(car(x)))))
defun(cadddr,(x),car(cdr(cdr(cdr(x)))))

/*build lists [^ppnarg found in:comp.lang.c ^variadic functions:k&r2]
  list() variadic macro uses ppnarg.h to count the arguments and call listn
https://github.com/luser-dr00g/sexp.c/blob/master/ppnarg.h
  listn() variadic function copies n (int) arguments to memory and call lista
  lista() constructs a list of n elements from pointer to memory
 */
int lista(int c,int*a){int z=NIL;for(;c;)z=cons(a[--c],z);return z;}
int listn(int c,...){va_list a;int*z=n;
    va_start(a,c);for(;c--;)*n++=va_arg(a,int);va_end(a);
    c=n-z;return lista(c,z);}
#define list(...) listn(PP_NARG(__VA_ARGS__),__VA_ARGS__)

/*auxiliary functions [^jmc]*/
defun(eq,(x,y),x==y)
defun(ff,(x),atomp(x)?x:ff(car(x))) /* find first atom */
defun(subst,(x,y,z),atomp(z)?(eq(z,y)?x:z): cons(subst(x,y,car(z)),subst(x,y,cdr(z))))
defun(equal,(x,y),(atomp(x)&&atomp(y)&&eq(x,y))
        ||(consp(x)&&consp(y)&&equal(car(x),car(y))&&equal(cdr(x),cdr(y)))) /*lists equal?*/
defun(null,(x),listp(x)&&val(x)==0) /*list == NIL?*/

/*association lists [^jmc]*/
defun(append,(x,y),null(x)?y:cons(car(x),append(cdr(x),y)))
defun(among,(x,y),!null(y)&&equal(x,car(y))||among(x,cdr(y)))
defun(pair,(x,y),null(x)&&null(y)?NIL:consp(x)&&consp(y)? cons(list(car(x),car(y)),pair(cdr(x),cdr(y))):0)
defun(assoc,(x,y),eq(caar(y),x)?cadar(y):null(y)?0:assoc(x,cdr(y)))

/*the universal function eval() [^jmc]*/
defun(sub2,(x,z),null(x)?z:eq(caar(x),z)?cadar(x):sub2(cdr(x),z))
defun(sublis,(x,y),atomp(y)?sub2(x,y):cons(sublis(x,car(y)),sublis(x,cdr(y))))
defun(apply,(f,args),eval(cons(f,appq(args)),NIL))
defun(appq,(m),null(m)?NIL:cons(list(atom("QUOTE"),car(m)),appq(cdr(m))))
defun(eval,(e,a),
    //prnlst(e), printf("\n"),
    numberp(e)?e:
    atomp(e)?assoc(e,a):
    atomp(car(e))?(
                   eq(car(e),atom("QUOTE"))?cadr(e):
                   eq(car(e),atom("ATOM"))? atomp(eval(cadr(e),a)):
                   eq(car(e),atom("EQ"))?   eval(cadr(e),a)==eval(caddr(e),a):
                   eq(car(e),atom("COND"))? evcon(cdr(e),a):
                   eq(car(e),atom("CAR"))?  car(eval(cadr(e),a)):
                   eq(car(e),atom("CDR"))?  cdr(eval(cadr(e),a)):
                   eq(car(e),atom("CONS"))? cons(eval(cadr(e),a),eval(caddr(e),a)):
                   eq(car(e),atom("DEFUN"))?
                       (a=list(atom("LABEL"),cadr(e),list(atom("LAMBD"),caddr(e),cadddr(e))),
                       env=append(env, list(list(cadr(e),a))), a):
        eval(cons(assoc(car(e),a),cdr(e)),a)):
        //eval(cons(assoc(car(e),a),evlis(cdr(e),a)),a) ): /*<jmc ^rootsoflisp*/
    objectp(car(e))?evobj(e,a):
    eq(caar(e),atom("LABEL"))? /*LABEL*/
        eval(cons(caddar(e),cdr(e)),cons(list(cadar(e),car(e)),a)):
    eq(caar(e),atom("LAMBD"))? /*LAMBDA with 5-char atoms */
        eval(caddar(e),append(pair(cadar(e),evlis(cdr(e),a)),a)):
    0)
defun(evcon,(c,a),eval(caar(c),a)?eval(cadar(c),a):evcon(cdr(c),a))
defun(evlis,(m,a),null(m)?NIL:cons(eval(car(m),a),evlis(cdr(m),a)))
int evobj(e,a){
    union object o = *(union object*)(m+val(car(e)));
    switch(o.tag){
    default: return 0;
    case SUBR: return o.f.f(eval(cadr(e),a));
    case FSUBR: return o.f.f(cdr(e));
    case SUBR2: return o.f.f(eval(cadr(e),a),eval(caddr(e),a));
    case FSUBR2: return o.f.f(cadr(e),caddr(e));
    }
}
defun(maplist,(x,f),null(x)?NIL:cons(apply(f,x),maplist(cdr(x),f)))

defun(assocpair,(x,y),eq(caar(y),x)?car(y):null(y)?0:assocpair(x,cdr(y)))
int set(x,y){
    int a=assocpair(x,env);
    if (a) rplacd(a,list(y));
    else env=append(list(list(x,y)),env);
    return y;
}

defun(prnenc,(x),x&&printf("%c",encoding[x]))
defun(prnatom,(unsigned x),prnatom0(x>>2),printf(" "))
defun(prnatom0,(x),prnenc(((x&63)+enc('T'))%64),prnatomn(x>>6))
defun(prnatomn,(x),x&63&&(prnenc(x&63),prnatomn(x>>6)))

defun(prn,(x),atomp(x)?prnatom(x): /*print with dot-notation [^stackoverflow]*/
    numberp(x)?printf("%d ",val(x)):
    objectp(x)?printf("OBJ_%d ",val(x)):
    consp(x)?printf("( "),prn(car(x)),printf(". "),prn(cdr(x)),printf(") "):
    printf("NIL "))

#define LPAR "("
#define RPAR ")"
defun(prnlstn,(x),!listp(x)?prn(x):
        ((car(x)?prnlst(car(x)):0),(cdr(x)?prnlstn(cdr(x)):0)))
defun(prnlst,(x),!listp(x)?prn(x):
        (printf(LPAR),(car(x)?prnlst(car(x)):0),(cdr(x)?prnlstn(cdr(x)):0),printf(RPAR)))

rd(char**p){int i,t,u,v,z; /*read a list [^stackoverflow]*/
    char boffo[6] = "";
    if(!(**p))return 0;
    if(**p==' ')return++(*p),rd(p);
    if(**p==*RPAR)return++(*p),atom(RPAR);
    if(**p==*LPAR){++(*p);
        z=NIL;
        u=rd(p);
        if (u!=atom(RPAR)){
            z=cons(u,NIL);
            while(u=rd(p),!eq(u,atom(RPAR)))u=cons(u,NIL),z=append(z,u);
        }
        return z;}
    if(**p>='0'&&**p<='9'){
        int v = **p - '0';
        while(*++*p>='0'&&**p<='9') v*=10, v+=**p-'0';
        return number(v);
    }
    for(i=0;i<-1+sizeof boffo;i++){
        if (isspace((*p)[i]) || (*p)[i]=='\0') break;
        if (!strchr(encoding,(*p)[i])) break;
        if (strchr("()",(*p)[i])) break;
        boffo[i]=(*p)[i];
    }
    boffo[i]='\0';
    (*p)+=i;
    return atom(boffo);
}

//void fix(x){signal(SIGSEGV,fix);sbrk(sizeof(int)*(msz*=2));} /*grow memory in response to memory-access fault*/
int main(){
    //char *s;
    char s[BUFSIZ];
    char *p;
    int x;

    /* improved assertions thanks to Tim Rentsch, cf.
       https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.c/FZldZaPpTT4/5g4bWdsxAwAJ */
    assert((-1 & 3) == 3); /* that ints are 2's complement */
    assert((-1 >> 1) < 0); /* that right shift keeps sign */
    //assert((-1>>1)==-1);  /*require 2's-complement and right-shift must be sign-preserving */
    //printf("");  /* exercise stdio so it (hopefully) malloc's what it needs before we take sbrk() */
    //snprintf(NULL, 0, "%c%d%f", 'x', 42, 72.27);
    //n=m=sbrk(sizeof(int)*(msz=getpagesize()));*n++=0;*n++=0; /*initialize memory and begin at cell 2*/
    //signal(SIGSEGV,fix); /*might let it run longer, obscures problems*/
    n=m=calloc(msz=getpagesize(),sizeof(int));

    env = list(
            list(atom("T"),atom("T")),
            list(atom("NIL"),NIL),
            list(atom("CAAR"),subr1(caar)),
            list(atom("CADR"),subr1(cadr)),
            list(atom("CDDR"),subr1(cddr)),
            list(atom("CADAR"),subr1(cadar)),
            list(atom("CADDR"),subr1(caddr)),
            list(atom("CDDDR"),subr1(cdddr)),
            list(atom("SET"),subr2(set)),
            list(atom("SETQ"),fsubr2(set))
            );

    while(1) {
        //printf("env:\n"); prnlst(env); printf("\n");
        printf(">");
        fflush(0);
        if (!fgets(s,sizeof s,stdin))
            break;
        s[strlen(s)-1]=0;
        p = s;
        x = rd (&p);
        //printf ("%s\n", s);

        //prn(x); printf("\n");
        //prnlst(x);
        //fflush(0);
        //printf ("\nEVAL\n");
        x = eval(x, env);

        //printf ("x: %d\n", x);
        //printf ("0: %o\n", x);
        //printf ("0x: %x\n", x);
        //printf ("tag(x): %d\n", tag (x));
        //printf ("val(x): %d\n", val (x));
        //printf ("car(x): %d\n", car (x));
        //printf ("cdr(x): %d\n", cdr (x));
        //prn (x); printf("\n");
        prnlst(x); printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Ok the parts I don't like are actually the parts that still look too much like C. Although I expect opinions may very well differ. I think I know what to do with this one (compound literal):

```
int objfunc(enum objecttag t, int(*f)()){
    union object *o = (union object *)n;
    //n+=(int)ceil((double)sizeof*o/sizeof*n);
    n+=(sizeof*o+sizeof*n-1)/sizeof*n;
    o->f.tag = t;
    o->f.f = f;
    return object((int*)o-m);
}
```

But the *read* function (`rd()`) does not have the same character as the rest of the piece. But I've looked at it too long without seeing where to improve it. At one point it [didn't even work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096456/why-wont-my-little-lisp-quote) and I needed help to figure out the problem.

```
rd(char**p){int i,t,u,v,z; /*read a list [^stackoverflow]*/
    char boffo[6] = "";
    if(!(**p))return 0;
    if(**p==' ')return++(*p),rd(p);
    if(**p==*RPAR)return++(*p),atom(RPAR);
    if(**p==*LPAR){++(*p);
        z=NIL;
        u=rd(p);
        if (u!=atom(RPAR)){
            z=cons(u,NIL);
            while(u=rd(p),!eq(u,atom(RPAR)))u=cons(u,NIL),z=append(z,u);
        }
        return z;}
    if(**p>='0'&&**p<='9'){
        int v = **p - '0';
        while(*++*p>='0'&&**p<='9') v*=10, v+=**p-'0';
        return number(v);
    }
    for(i=0;i<-1+sizeof boffo;i++){
        if (isspace((*p)[i]) || (*p)[i]=='\0') break;
        if (!strchr(encoding,(*p)[i])) break;
        if (strchr("()",(*p)[i])) break;
        boffo[i]=(*p)[i];
    }
    boffo[i]='\0';
    (*p)+=i;
    return atom(boffo);
}
```

Errhhmmmm. Yeah. It does have the beloved `boffo` which I found described in the [LISP 1.0 manual](https://kyber.io/rawvids/LISP_I_Programmers_Manual_LISP_I_Programmers_Manual.pdf) as the buffer used to convert names from string representation to internal representation. Although in the Lisp 1.0, it just used the native byte encoding of the machine. My 6bit code is another problem. It packs a string into an integer but with the severe limit of only 5 letters per name. So it will  run all the constructs from the Micromanual Lisp paper *iff* you spell `LAMBDA` as `LAMBD`. But it would add more complexity to do string handling I think. Something like the UTF encoding's multi-byte format might be usable to overcome the 5 character limit, I think.

The printing code changed from loops into recursive functions pretty easily, but the reader code still smacks of procedural thinking.

One further highlight which should look dangerous but I think (hope) I've crossed all my T's on is doing right shifts on signed integers. This is not a behavior that is guaranteed by the standard. But it is the (dare I say) *natural* result on all consumer or hobby machines which are likely to run this code. I use asserts to check that integers are 2's complement and that right-shifting preserves the sign so I can do this right shifting to remove the 2-bit tag from encoded numbers; and negative integers within the 30-bit range will successfully make the round-trip through encoding and decoding.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

### Overcoming the 5 character limit on names

Make the `val(x)` of the object be a hash value which maps the full string in a string table.

I think the `T == 1` and `NIL == 0` property can be maintained simply by forcing 0 to be the index of `"T"`.

Then all the special encoding stuff can just be removed. It's fun and cool, but unnecessary distraction when the rest of the program is already so strange.

### Assumes 32-bit without explicit assertion

Yep. Tssk.